# Error: OAuth authentication requires session support

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session, passport-twitter

I am trying to simply make use of Twitter OAuth for my web app.
Thats my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const passport = require("passport");
const session = require("express-session");
require("./services/passport");

const app = express();

require("./routes/authRoutes")(app);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "keyboard cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(passport.session());

app.listen(5000);
```

Now even though I implemented session I still get the error that session support is required:

```
Error: OAuth authentication requires session support. Did you forget to use express-session middleware?
```

I've gone through dozen of github issues and stackoverflow questions but can't find the right answer. Hope you can help me

Answer (score 3):

you need to put require("./routes/authRoutes")(app) statement after all middlewares here like session and passport.

Can you try by putting above require statement one line before app.listen.

Comment: Thank you. How could I not see that.